# Show UIImageView at a size smaller than its intrinsic size

Tags: ios, swift

Having adopted Autolayout and Storyboards, I'm no longer designing screens at exact dimensions, so when I use images I tend to use a fairly large sized image so that it will look sharp on the iPad but can be scaled down for the smaller iPhones. I drag this image into the Asset Catalog.

When I place the image into a View Controller in my Storyboard, the image wants to be its intrinsic size. I can only get it to show smaller by setting a specific width, proportional width to another object, or by constraining it between two other items.

I'm now at another point of the project where I need to add the image in code. Although I am setting a specific height and width for the image's frame, the image still appears on screen at its intrinsic size and not where I have set it using:

```
myImage.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 50, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Set `contentMode` as `ScaleAspectFit // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent`

Comment: I do set myImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit / the aspect stays fixed but it grows beyond the defined width & height of the frame...

Comment: You should set constraint `width` and `height` for this `image view`.

Answer (score 1):

I look you want add an `imageView` in `CenterX` and `margin top 100`. And hold image aspect in square size 100, 100. This code below will help you.

```
    let imageName = "your image name in resource"
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    self.view.addSubview(imageView)

    // add your constraint
    let constTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute:.Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    //        var constLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.center.x - 50)

    var constCenterX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);

    var constWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 100);
    var constHight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 100);

    imageView.addConstraints([constHight, constWidth])
    self.view.addConstraints([constTop, constCenterX])
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the UIImageView's `contentMode` which is actually a property of `UIView`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@UIViewContentMode

If you take on layout in code, I hope you're doing it in the right place... by overriding `layoutSubviews()`, and if *that* needs to get triggered by an external event, that the event fires `setNeedsLayout()` on the parent view.

Lots of handshaking and configuring to do if it must be done in code.